# Can I pass javascript variable to a PHP form?

Tags: php, javascript

I'm using jcrop to crop my photos and need to send the current values along with my form submission. Is there an easy way to do this?

The JavaScript variable is this:

```
c = coords;
$.param(c)
```

Can I include this as a hidden field in my PHP form somehow?

```
<input type="hidden" name="coords" value=" ??? " />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course you can:

```
<form onsubmit='document.getElementById("your-hidden-field-id").value = c.toString(); return true;'>
...
<input type="hidden" name="coords" id="your-hidden-field-id"/>
</form>
```

Comment: I'm trying the follwoing but crop_coords is always empty:  <form id="process_image_form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post" onsubmit='$("#crop_cords").val() = $.param(c).toString(); return true;'>

Comment: The value of $.param(c).toString() is valid.

Comment: There are several things wrong in your code. First you probably mistyped `crop_coords`. Second, `.val()` is a getter, not a setter.

Comment: Cicada: That was it: $("#crop_cords").val($.param(c).toString()) worked! Thanks!